# ExtJS GridPanel Row Click

Tags: extjs

I have designed an ExtJS GridPanel and populated data from a database.
My requirement is when clicking on a grid row (like edit button) get an id from the grid and  populate a window with specific data (retrive data using id from database).
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
            grid.on('rowclick', function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
                console.log(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e);
            }, this);
```

Edit: Refer [ExtJS Grid FAQ](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_FAQ_Grid) section for Grid related issues

Comment: According to this [doc page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-rowclick), the arguments of rowclick event handler should be like this:

`rowclick( this, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts )`

Answer (score 1):

Add it in grid's Listener:

```
listeners: {
    cellclick: function (grd, rowIndex, colIndex, e) {
       var record = grd.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
       var record = grd.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to this [doc page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-cellclick), the arguments of `celllcick` handler should be like this:        


`cellclick( this, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts )`

Comment: Please note: This above code was written for version 3.4. For obvious reasons, any upgrade in Sencha version(5.0 in this case) may add/subtract prametrized methods. You have to check accordingly. Let me know if there is anything specific which you are struggling with ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/form/form-grid.html) from [Ext JS 3.3 Examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/), it features similar mechanics to what you have described. The main source code can be seen [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/form/form-grid.js).

The other official Grid-related examples (data binding etc.) are probably worth a look as well.

Comment: hmmm... all your link is href to version 4 final release.. sencha has update it..